# USB Barcode scanner.

Tags: ubuntu, usb, drivers, barcode-scanner

I have a USB Zebex barcode scanner, this device works properly using Windows XP and Windows Vista when I open Notepad.

However I can't get it to work on Ubuntu. I open Gedit, and it makes the same noise as in Windows, but nothing scans.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Looking around, I see that it also doesn't work in Xubuntu. In OpenSuse it works without a problem. Maybe you need some additional drivers (keyboard, maybe?).

Comment: It's really weird, going to have to search for a solution

Comment: usb keyword works 100%

Comment: This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/586905/99408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you could try:

```
xinput list
```

This will give you a list of all input devices that are recognized by Xorg and allows you to enable or disable devices as well as test them (replace `${DEVICEID}` with what is displayed by `xinput list`):

```
xinput set-int-prop ${DEVICEID} 'Device Enabled' 32 1
xinput test ${DEVICEID}
```

Second thing you could try would be the more low-level `evtest` tool (replace `/dev/input/eventX` with the proper device file):

```
evtest /dev/input/eventX
```

It should print events to the screen when it gets data. `evtest` is part of the `joystick` package in Ubuntu.

Neither of these will make your Barcode scanner work, but they will allow you to figure out where the problem is. If `evtest` works, but `xinput` doesn't, then you have to tweak your Xorg.conf and manually add it as extra keyboard, if neither works then its a Kernel driver problem.

Answer (score 2):

Does the sound come from the PC speakers or from the scanner?

Check and make sure the scanner is properly detected

```
dmesg
```

and see if you have something that looks like this when you plug in the scanner

```
usb 5-1: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
usb 5-1: new device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0001
usb 5-1: new device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
usb 5-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
input: HID 0000:0001 as /class/input/input6
input: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [HID 0000:0001] on usb-0000:00:10.3-1
```

if you see the above, then you should also see events in `dmesg` after you push the scan button.

if you dont see the above, then you probably need to initialize the usb keyboard module with 
you might try

```
sudo modprobe usbkbd
```

- reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=988219

Comment: Yes, it makes a noise. initialized the usb keyboard and still nothing